# MOSFET: why does it conduct after init?

Tags: power, mosfet

I have a pretty interesting observation of a MOSFET (5LP01SP).

Here is my schematic (it is not simplified at all, I have this on my desk):

[image]

The thing is: BT1 is an intelligent powerbank: it turns on when it's being loaded (by at least 5mA), then it stays on as long as drawn current is at least 100mA.
If drawn current drops below 100mA, it turns off after 20s. And it can only turn back on if drawn current drastically drops below 20uA first (practically when you disconnect the USB device from the powerbank). 20uA by experience: I can load the bank with 330k, and it doesn't turn on. Moreover, with leaving the 330k connected, I can make it turn on with applying an extra load by 100R (parallel with 330k). Then it turns off, and I can turn it back again without disconnecting the 330k.

I wish to control this powerbank, and I thought on a FET to kind of faking the USB disconnect to the bank.

Interesting observation: when I attach this circuit to the bank, the bank doesn't turn on. This is great.

However, afterwards, when I try drawing some current between ST1 and ST2 (with S1 OFF) the FET seems opening for a marginally short time which triggers the powerbank to turn on.

Which parameter is worth checking about this initial behaviour of this FET?

Although the bank turns on, any load between ST1 and ST2 doesn't get power (as the FET stabilises and close after that marginally short time)

I could live with this.

After 20s the bank will power down.

However, after it's being powered down, it can't be turned back on without removing the whole circuit from it, and reconnecting.

So I think the bank registers the MOSFET's initial current leakage, then the MOSFET is still leaking some small current that makes the bank not believe that the device is actually disconnected.
This bothers very much, as this prevents me from controlling the bank.

Note: controlling is easy and not drawn here on schematic: it's another push button on the bank with a 100R resistor.

I can turn the bank on with this 100R only if I don't put any load between ST1 and ST2.

I would stay away from relays, although it would be a straightforward solution but it also has its disadvantages.

So altogether I have 2 questions implied here:

Q1: Which parameter is worth checking about this initial behaviour of this FET?

Q2: even digital multimeter measures the initial current drawn by the loaded FET, however it immediately goes back to 0uA (in 2mA threshold). How could I make the bank believe nothing is connected?

Comment: 5LP01SP is only good for switching ~10mA. Doesn't seem appropriate for a power bank that needs at least 100mA to stay turned on.

Comment: Yes. But the question is why does it turns it on at all?

Comment: Miller capacitance (Cdg) should be specified in the datasheet. You may need to artificially increase Cgs by adding a couple nF across R1 to compensate for this.

Comment: Yes Miller capacitance is probably the reason. But a FET suitable for switching >>100mA will have much higher capacitance than this one, and then the problem will be much harder to solve.  So, how much current do you need to switch?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to happen due to gate capacitance of the MOSFET, which is of the order of 5pF typically, check the datasheet if you want specifics (which aren't important). So you have an RC circuit on the gate, and the MOSFET conducts for a mere fraction of a second.

The solution to this would look like this:

[image]

During the power-on voltage spike the capacitor will let that spike (AC component) through to charge the capacitor quickly/instantly. It requires testing of course.

Here is a similar thing applied in a 2016 Macbook Pro:

[image]

You need a small cap for that. Give it a try and see if it helps. Try various cap sizes. You want smaller ESR if possible.

**EDIT**

After connecting gate directly to power line, it turned out it doesn't work and still turns the power bank on. So it could be the initial load current when connecting.

Something you could try to deal with it. Also requires testing, naturally. For testing, pretty much any common one should do. Diode is a must unless you want to burn stuff with 50V spikes:

[image]

Comment: @Daniel I'll go to the chat. This is getting really long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134211/discussion-between-ilya-and-daniel).